# How to save multiple functions as each files(*.sql) in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql-8.2

I'm using PostgreSQL version 8.2 and trying to save all functions/views source code as each files on a local.
But it seems to be impossible to extract each function's code to each files.

> example:
>
> I'd like to save source files like below:
>
> function a1, a2, a3 -----> a1.sql, a2.sql, a3.sql

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution, but should get you started in the right direction.

---

Assuming you are using `psql` for this, you can save the source code of a single function by spooling the output of `select procsrc from pg_proc where proname = '...'` to a file, e.g.:

```sql
\t
\a
\o a1.sql
select prosrc from pg_proc where proname = 'a1';
\o
```

The `\t \a` configures `psql` to only output the content of the column `prosrc`. The `\o a1.sql` redirects the query result to a file.

As you want one file per function, you need to run this for each function. You can either do this manually or generate a script which does this by running a SQL statement:

```sql
\t \a \o extract_source.sql
select concat('\t '\a \o ', proname, '.sql', chr(10), 
              'select prosrc from pg_proc where proname = ''', proname, ''';', 
              chr(10), 
              '\o', chr(10))
from pg_proc;
\o 
\i extract_source.sql
```

The query generates the first script for each procedure, then runs the generated script.

**Not tested**, you probably need to tweak that to meet your needs.

---

Note that the content of `prosrc` is **NOT** the complete function.

It lacks the return type, the arguments and the language definition. In more modern Postgres versions you could use `pg_get_functiondef()` for that, but with 8.2 you  will need to put all those things together using the columns from `pg_proc`. The most complicated part is getting the function arguments right (because Postgres 8.2 also lacks, `pg_get_function_arguments()`)

Without the arguments, it will be something like:

```sql
select concat('create or replace function ', 
              proname, '(......) ', 
              'returns ', rt.typname, 
              ' as $$ ', 
              prosrc, 
              '$$ language ', l.lanname, ';')
from pg_proc p
  join pg_language l on l.oid = p.prolang
  join pg_type rt on rt.oid = p.prorettype
where proname = 'a1';
```

instead of "just" `select prosrc .... from pg_proc`.